How to retrieve order book for newly created tokens in Solana network using python?
How to retrieve order book for newly created tokens in Solana network using python? Everything points to the Serum API, but I am getting errors when trying to import PublicKey from the Solana library. Are there any other ways to do this?
Code:
from pyserum.connection import conn
from pyserum.market import Market
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

# Replace with your Serum market address and program ID
market_address = '4k3Dyjzvzp8eTxPZsHNT4X14X5R3FLeGkwWxNGj39fub'  # Example for SOL/USDC
serum_program_id = '9xQeWvG8169dZ2ib6KMvZr9VvJHZo2R5mPbiJQF1XhCk'  # Standard Serum program ID for mainnet
# Connect to the Solana mainnet-beta cluster
client = conn('')

# Load the market instance using the client, market address, and program ID
market = Market.load(client, Pubkey(market_address), Pubkey(serum_program_id))

# Retrieve the order book data for bids and asks
bids = market.load_bids()
asks = market.load_asks()

# Print order book details
print("Bids:")
for bid in bids:
    print(f"Price: {bid.price}, Size: {bid.size}")

print("\nAsks:")
for ask in asks:
    print(f"Price: {ask.price}, Size: {ask.size}")

Error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solana.publickey'
FYI I have installed Solana lib
